# Content as NextPage pagination link in Tumblr

Tags: pagination, tumblr

I'm creating a single post per page tumblr template with the body content as the link to the next page - you can see a quick [test working here](http://testb12.tumblr.com):

There are 4 entries but the 4th doesn't render, probably because there is no 'NextPage'. Any idea how I might get around that to render the last page? or if it is has to be blank how to render a bit of static text.

```
{block:Text} 
 <div class="content">  
  {block:Pagination}  
   {block:NextPage}  
    <a href="{NextPage}">{Body}</a>  
    {/block:NextPage}  
  {/block:Pagination}  
 </div> 
{/block:Text}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
{block:Text} 
 <div class="content">  
  {block:Pagination}  
   {block:NextPage}  
    <a href="{NextPage}">
   {/block:NextPage}  
  {/block:Pagination}  
     {Body}
  {block:Pagination}  
   {block:NextPage}  
    </a>  
   {/block:NextPage}  
  {/block:Pagination}  
 </div> 
{/block:Text}
```

This way the `{Body}` should always render, and the link only if there is a next page!

Comment: @mark: There is a button that looks like the outline of a checkmark, press it to accept a solution!